# How to hide the app from the play store for only specific search

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Let's assume the name of the app is "Alpha" and there are three apps for "Alpha".

- First (main app) => Name: "Alpha", bundle name: "com.alpha.customer"
- Second (delivery partner app) => Name: "Alpha Delivery Partner",
  bundle Name: "com.alpha.delivery"
- Third (rider app) => Name: "Alpha Rider", bundle Name:
  "com.alpha.rider"

Now what I have to do is when the user types "Alpha" on the play store then he/she is only able to view First (main app) only, not the other two apps (currently it shows all three apps).

And for the other two apps, they should only be visible when the user types the whole name of the app.

Comment: As per my knowledge it's not possible, You can change the package name or you can upload your app with new deverloper account

Answer (score 0):

- Your title should be unique and accessible, avoid standard terms, and reinforce what your app is about.
- Keep your title focused. Long labels may be shortened on some devices that your users are browsing on.
- Avoid using subtle misspellings of general terms, as users may
  correct misspelt search terms.

Source - Google
You can check it from [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=en)

Make sure your app SEO is good and also make sure your app must be shown on the web search too.

Make your app name unique and use the same name in the developer app file.